# Update multiple rows where id is the same in one query (laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I dont know if the question is asked correctly, but here it is. I have maybe 60+ variables:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$job_type_buyer = $_POST['job_type_buyer'];
$job_type_partner = $_POST['job_type_partner'];
$job_type_locum = $_POST['job_type_locum'];
// etc...
```

I want to update multiple rows at once, where for example `$id = 3;`

My table structure is something like this:

```
meta_id    id    meta_key          meta_value
1          3     job_type_buyer    1
2          3     job_type_partner  0
// etc...
```

At the moment, i am running multiple queries to achieve what i want:

```
DB::table('people_job_types')
 ->where('id', $id)
 ->where('meta_key', 'job_type_buyer')
 ->update( ['meta_value' => $job_type_buyer] 
);

DB::table('people_job_types')
 ->where('id', $id)
 ->where('meta_key', 'job_type_partner')
 ->update( ['meta_value' => $job_type_partner] 
);

// etc...
```

I know that this might take a while to initiate and the code structure is wrong itself.

**Question:**

How to update all rows at once, by one query? Should i use arrays?

Sorry for bad english and thanks for any answers.

Comment: you can try some loops like `for, while` ?

Comment: Hmm, any examples? :)

Comment: Since you're using Laravel, which is great, why are you referencing `$_POST` directly? You're supposed to fetch the arguments via the controller `$request` object.

Comment: @tadman because i have tons of code like this to do, and i thought that this will be the fastest way, since this will be only on local office network.

Comment: @Tauras Do it the Laravel way and you'll find your life is a lot easier. Parameters can come in from a variety of sources, both embedded in the route, from the query-string arguments, and via POST data that may be encoded in JSON or XML. Don't access low-level primitives out of convenience. You're actually making things more difficult. Don't worry about performance unless you have a *measurable* performance problem. Premature optimization is the death of many projects.

Comment: @tadman can you please write answer with simple code example which i will be able to accept? By the way, i am doing this with ajax (but thats different story)... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

Try something like below. I hope it helps to you

```
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){

DB::table('people_job_types')
 ->where('id', $id) 
->where('meta_id', '1') //here that id just pass it loop like 1 n 2....
 ->where('meta_key', '$job_type_partner')
 ->update( ['meta_value' => $job_type_partner] 
);

}
```

Comment: Not working. Maybe my question is wrong. I just want to update all meta_keys with given meta_values in variables, which is named same as meta_key. :/

Comment: No, but it just not working with your code. Also, i did not understanded ``->where('meta_key', '$job_type_partner')`` this part. I want to select all meta_keys by id and set values for that meta_keys which is in variables.